# How to close a page opened in ionic using $stateProvider and $urlRouterProvider

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I have created a page in ionic, when user clicks on button it opens another page using following code.

```
$location.url('/customer_service_description');
```

Inside this customer_service_description page there is a button,when this button is clicked the users get redirect to the previous page(home page) using following code

```
$location.url('/customer_home');
```

But instead of redirecting user to home page I want the current page to be closed so that when user clicks back button on home page they don't get redirected to customer_service_description page

Comment: On back click you might have to clear page stack history from `customer_service_description` page after user is redirected.

Comment: The above method is an efficient one but I solved the issue by $ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction and redirected the home page to where ever I want when user clicks back button

Comment: Yeah thats a way too. On back press do nothing so app wont go back.

Answer (score 0):

What I done is I redirected the button clicks in customer_service_description to customer_home page using following method

```
$location.url('/customer_home');
```

In the customer_home page to prevent the app from opening the customer_service_description page I have used following code

```
$ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(function () {
    window.location = "#/redirect_where_u_want"; 
}, 100);
```